# gdb runs in the context of another process?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb

I just want to understand how gdb (or anyother debugger) can modify memory in the address space of another process?

we have a running process, we attach to it

> attach `pid`

from here on we can modify the memory (variables) which is in the 'attached process' address space. How is this possible. What is stopping anyother processes (not a debugger) in doing the same. Does OS provide special `doors` which can  be used by the debuggers to peek/modify a different process's address space?

or am I getting this wrong. After the attach does the process run within the context of the debugger? if so how does the change in this context happen? if this happens, can I assume this will be a copy on write? if so the debugger will have a different memory with the modified data. But once we modify some memory from gdb and detach from the process, the process will continue to see the modified data.... Does this mean that gdb has access to the address spece of this running process?

Any pointers to understand this will be appreciated. I can look at the code of gdb, but the code is HUGE, did not know where to start.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Linux, the API is [`ptrace()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace). It requires certain privileges, which are spelled out in the man page.

For a tutorial on how to use it, see [Playing with ptrace](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6100).